# CLFLUSH in virtualization environment

Tags: linux, x86, cpu, virtualization, instructions

I have read the [document](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_30.html) about the CLFLUSH instruction of Intel x86 machine. 
I understand that `CLFLUSH m8` means flush the cache line containing linear address m8  if I run the instruction inside a Linux module on the bare metal.

However, what if I want to run the instruction inside a VM in virtualization environment? What the parameter of `CLFLUSH` is? 
To be specific, suppose I want to flush a cache line that hold the content for virtual address `va` of a program in a VM. The virtual address `va` is mapped to physical address `pa` in the VM, and `pa` will be mapped to the machine address `ma` in the VMM/hypervisor. Which address should I use for the `CLFLUSH` instruction, `va`, `pa` or `ma`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Let's answer this way. I'm sure you'll agree that software should run identically in virtualized and non-virtualized environments, and that ideally it should be unable to tell it is being virtualized. The answer to your question immediately follows; You use whichever address you would have used had it been running bare-metal, simply because you (should) have no way to tell whether you are, in fact, running bare-metal or not.

Comment: This is a nice observation! I agree. However, the reason why software have no idea if it runs in virtualized or non-virtualized environment is because the VMM/hypervisor virtualized the instruction. If the VMM does not support this instruction and I want to extend the VMM's hypercall to support it, I will have to know which address the hypervisor should use for the CLFLUSH instruction. Am I correct?

Comment: If hypervisor can use the `va` address, I'm wondering how hardware can figure out which cache line should be flushed based on the `va`? On bare metal, I can understand that the hardware can use CR3 register to transfer the `va` to machine address to find the cache line to flush. But in virtualized environment, will the hardware do the translation from `va` to `ma` automatically?

Comment: I am leafing it right now, but I strongly suspect you'll find the nitty-gritty details in the [Intel Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf), Volume 3, Section 23-33 but especially 28 "VMX SUPPORT FOR ADDRESS TRANSLATION". Long story short, an Intel processor has the option of maintaining additional bookkeeping information, in the shape of a VPID for each linear address translation. Then there can exist multiple mappings for the same linear address, but they differ in VPID.

Comment: yeah, that's true... intel uses VPID to distinguish the linear address from different VMs. This may indicate that I have to issue CLFLUSH when the owner program of the address is still running. Otherwise, I will have to load the VPID and CR3 to issue CLFLUSH. Loading CR3 has already flush the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clflush` is not a privileged instruction.  User processes can run it, just like they can run load, store, prefetch, and `movnt` (store with cache eviction) instructions which also affect the cache.

I expect it virtualizes just fine, without any hypervisor support, since it uses addresses the same way other memory references do.

Since hardware virtualization allows the CPU to do a full translation from guest virtual addresses to hardware physical addresses, the desired behaviour (cache line synced to physical memory) should happen without hypervisor intervention.

Comment: I cant find this one in the manual, the vmcs has two fields 0x00006C06 and 0x00006C08 commonly referred to as fs and gs bases
does it mean the MSRs ?
or the segments?
I've looked at other hypervisor sources and some do segment, some do MSRs
0x00006C0A is the TR base, which everyone uses the seg base?

Comment: I'm sorry for tagging you every time but you are my god saver

Comment: @zerocool: That has nothing to do with this question or answer.  But I'd assume those are for the segment *base*, i.e. virtual address, like the normal MSRs or `wrfsbase`.  The segment *register* value itself (the selector) is not the base, so using the word "base" rules that out.  Also, nobody uses the segment register values for anything, usually leaving them `0` (null selector) in 64-bit mode, without even making a GDT entry for them.